# In React, why does this onClick snippet of code work but not this other way ive tried to write it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Why does this work for the onClick

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  toggleCartHidden: () => dispatch(toggleCartHidden()),
});

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    history.push('/checkout');
    toggleCartHidden();
  }}
>Button text</Button>
```

But this doesnt work (the routing doesnt work)

```
<Button
  onClick={
    (() => {
      history.push('/checkout');
    },
    toggleCartHidden)
  }
>Button text</Button>
```

I have another component with similar code that works with this syntax with onClick (no function call within onClick)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  toggleCartHidden: () => dispatch(toggleCartHidden()),
});

<div className='cart-icon' onClick={toggleCartHidden}> ICON </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are passing an `expression` that is evaluated. At `expression` you use `,`  operator that evaluates each part, but it only returns the last one which is `toggleCartHidden`.

if you do `(1, 3, 5)` on your console it returns `5`.